# Proof that $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}X(w)P(\{w\})$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

The question is inspired by a theorem about the expected value of a discrete random variable: $$\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{x}xp(x)$$

if the series converges absolutely.

The theorem says that $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}X(w)P(\{w\})$.

To prove the theorem one proceed as follows:

1. $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{x}xp(x)$ by definition of $\mathbb E[X]$
2. $\sum_{x}xp(x)=\sum_{x}xP(X=x)$ by definition of $p(x)$
3. $\sum_{x}xP(X=x)=\sum_{x} x \sum_{\omega: X(w)=x} P(\{w\})$ by definition of $P(X=x)$ existence of which follows from the fact that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} P(\{w\}) = 1$
4. $\sum_{x} x \sum_{\omega: X(w)=x} P(\{w\})=\sum_{x}\sum_{\omega: X(w)=x} X(\omega)P(\{w\})$ here we just use a property of series (if each element of a series is multiplied by a number its sum also increases by the same number)
5. $\sum_{x}\sum_{\omega: X(w)=x} X(\omega)P(\{w\})=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(w)P(\{w\})$ to do this step should not one show that the series $\{P(\{\omega \})X(\omega)\}_{\omega \in \Omega}$ converges absolutely, so one can use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i,j} \text{ if } x_{i,j}$ converges absolutely?

And if one should, then how to prove this fact to complete the proof?